# SerialPort.Write method hanging, timeout not fired in C#

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port

I have to write a program that writes on a serial port but sometimes the call to the Write method hangs and the WriteTimeout is never fired so my program hangs indefinitely.

Here is the port creation code:

```
   void DetectX1BackgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        String[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
        int i = 0;
        foreach (string PortName in ports)
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Trying to open:" + PortName);
                SerialPort port = openSerial(PortName);
                Console.WriteLine("Port is open:" + PortName);
                port.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(port_DataReceived);
                port.Write("$ST+IMEI=0000\r\n");
                if (IMEIFoundEvent.WaitOne(250))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("IMEI Found:[" + imei + "]");
                    if (addresses.ContainsKey(imei))
                    {
                        ((BackgroundWorker)sender).ReportProgress(0, new X1Model(imei, PortName, addresses[imei]));
                    }
                    else
                        Console.WriteLine("imei not in file: " + imei);
                }
                port.Close();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Erreur port " + PortName + ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                i++;
                ((BackgroundWorker)sender).ReportProgress(i * 100 / ports.Length);
            }
        }
    }

   private SerialPort openSerial(string PortName)
    {
        SerialPort port = new SerialPort(PortName);
        port.BaudRate = 57600;
        port.DataBits = 8;
        port.StopBits = StopBits.One;
        port.Parity = Parity.None;
        port.ReceivedBytesThreshold = 1;
        port.Handshake = Handshake.None;
        port.DtrEnable = true;
        port.RtsEnable = true;
        port.WriteTimeout = 5000;
        port.ReadTimeout = 5000;
        if (!port.IsOpen)
            port.Open();
        return port;
    }
```

Is there anything I'm missing ? 
I don't know if it's relevant but I'm using Serial To USB Adapters.

Edit: I'm using Windows XP with .Net 4.0. The line doesnt't exceed 50 characters and ends by a EOL character.

Comment: What OS? Mono or MS? What .NET version? How much data are you writing?

Comment: I thank you for your interest I updated my post.

Comment: Are you actually writing `...\r\n` or is that just a placeholder for the data?

Comment: I actually write "$ST+IMEI=0000\r\n" to identify on which port devices are connected.

Comment: If I get the correct data in a defined time interval, then I know a device is connected. But I checked through VS, the program hangs undefinitely on the port.Write method in some cases while I expect it to timeout in worth case.

Comment: @ThierryYbt - Does it write successfully at all, or just hangs on the first attempt?

Comment: It hangs on some ports on the first attempt. I just want to ignore those ports as it is during the port detection..

Comment: I'm every thing else than an expert, but did you try experimenting with the parameters? I once wrote a java program with serial port read/write and choose a baud rate of 9600, which is also the value used in most examples. Just a guess.

Comment: I'm sure about the port configuration as I use the same in HyperTerminal to connect to the devices.

Answer (score 5):

I know it's an old question, which you've probably solved by now, but there's no accepted answer yet. I was having the same issue yesterday and seem to have fixed it -- were you setting the Write Timeout?

```
_serialPort.WriteTimeout = 500;
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.writetimeout.aspx

Comment: Well you can easily look into his code and you see that he sets port.WriteTimeout = 5000; So your answer is quite useless here.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to set the [`PortName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.portname.aspx).  You can get the list of ports from [`GetPortNames`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.getportnames.aspx).  This will typically be like `COM1` or `COM2`

Comment: Yes I didn't add that part of the code, but I'm actually looping through all ports to get my devices.

Comment: Are you opening and closing a lot of ports as you loop through?

Comment: Well I open try to write and read then close once for each port.

Comment: Isn't there a way to perform a non blocking Write call as I don't really care if it worked or not?

Comment: @ThierryYbt - See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1696559/95573).  You are probably not allowing enough time in between opening and closing.