# Application freezes during SerialPort.Open() - GPS module

Tags: c#, gps, serial-port

I’m writing an application which checks whether a (ublox) GPS module is installed in a machhine and if so it reads out the data via the serial interface. I do not know on which port, the module is working, so the program checks all COM ports for incoming signals at 4800 and 9600 baud.

The Ublox GPS module actually adapts to the baud rate (4800 or 9600).

The application often freezes during the search, turing GPS module off and on again solves this problem. The problem occurs sporadically directly after opening the COM port to which the GPS module is connected.

I have provided the SerialPort with a ReadTimeout, which however makes no changes in the error screen.

```
public static List<GPSDevicePort> DetectGPSSerialPorts()
{
    List<GPSDevicePort> ret = new List<GPSDevicePort>();
    List<int> baudrates = new List<int> { 4800, 9600 };

    foreach (string portName in SerialPort.GetPortNames())
    {
        foreach (int br in baudrates)
        {
            try
            {
                bool detected = false;

                using (SerialPort port = new SerialPort(portName, br))
                {
                    port.ReadTimeout = 1000;
                    port.DtrEnable = true;

                    // Auf GPS Daten warten...
                    Console.Write(string.Format("Opening {0} @ {1} Baud", portName, br));
                    port.Open();

                    int i = 0;
                    while(i < 5)
                    {
                        Console.Write("*");
                        string s = port.ReadExisting();

                        if (s.Contains("$GP"))
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("***[{0}@{1}]: {2}", portName, br, s));

                            GPSDevicePort devInfo = new GPSDevicePort(portName, port.BaudRate);
                            ret.Add(devInfo);

                            detected = true;
                            break;
                        }

                        i++;
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine("");
                    port.Close();
                    port.Dispose();
                }

                Thread.Sleep(1000);

                if (detected)
                    break;
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {}
        }
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Does this happen on your main application thread?

Comment: No it dosn't. My Main Application thread is my MainForm, which starts the function above (written in a DLL) in a thread.

Comment: When the system is frozen, can you pause execution in visual studio and see where in code you are?

Comment: No I can't, visual studio freezes too. Turning the gps-module off and on (via GPIO) will bring visial studio back to life.

Comment: I can see (in console) "Opening COM8 @ 4800 Baud" and the next Char '*' is already missing. So I guess it can only be the SerialPort.Open() Method.

Comment: If you left it for several minutes does it ever print the "*" char?

Comment: No, never. But I am wondering, that this is a sporadically error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59710/discussion-between-crazymetal-and-tremmors).

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696238/c-timeout-on-serialport-open) is someone else who has a problem where SerialPort.Open hangs for some time.  They suggest starting each SerialPort.Open on a new thread and killing it after some time.

This also has the added benefit of letting you open each serial port at the same time.  If you have 3 com ports, your code has a worst case execution time of 36 seconds.  Doing each of the 3 ports at the same time on separate threads would drop that to a worst case of 12 seconds.

Comment: Well, now I got (sporadically) a System.UnauthorizedAccessException" in System.dll instat the '*'-Char

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, it went away by using `SerilaPort.Dispose()` and retrying `SerialPort.Open()`. It looks like my program wasn't releasing the port resources from previous session so when I tryied to open again it hanged.