# C#, kill a serial that tries to connect after an certain time

Tags: c#, serial-port

I am trying to identify a serial port (COM) that receives a certain string.
Anyway, if I loop on each COM, C# locks the ReadLine after a connection on some ports (e.g. COM 10).

I am thinking to launch the `SerialPort` `.ReadLine()` on a new `Thread`, and after an amount of time I kill this thread.
Anyway, I am thinking if there is a more "elegant" way to achieve the same results.

Here are posted a part of the code:

```
String com=""; 
for (int i= 0; i< ports.Length; i++) //ports is an array of String, the elements are the opened COM
{
    mysp= new SerialPort(ports[i], 9600);
    try {
        mysp.Open(); 
        String temp = mysp.ReadLine(); //HERE  INFINITE LOOP ON CERTAIN PORTS
        if (temp.IndexOf("*") > -1)
        {
            com = ports[i]; //Set the correct COM port
            i = ports.Length;
            mysp.Close();
        }
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception "+e+" on " + ports[i]);
        mysp.Close();
    }
}
```

EDIT: I correct the questions, as suggest jdweng in the comments. It does not block on `.Open()` but it does block on `.ReadLine()`.

Comment: This looks like a hacky workaround for [same problem](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1696238/1997232). The real question is why it hangs (what port are you trying to open, is it exists, etc.), maybe you have problem with previous `Close()`. Btw, `SerialPort` implementation is really poor thing, many have already switched to own winapi wrappers.

Comment: The line String temp = mysp.ReadLine(); blocks until and CR is found in input.  Instead use an Async method which doesn't block.

Comment: Thanks @jdweng, it is correct, the software does not lock on Open, but on ReadLine. Now I try to look how async method works on C#.

Comment: Use the ReadTimeout property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could wrap the call in a `Task` with a specified timeout.

```
int timeout = 5000; // Cancel the task after 5 seconds
Task.Run(() => { 
    var temp = mysp.ReadLine(); //HERE  INFINITE LOOP ON CERTAIN PORTS
    if (temp.IndexOf("*") > -1)
    {
        com = ports[i]; //Set the correct COM port
        i = ports.Length;
        mysp.Close();
    }
}).Wait(timeout);
```

Should also move the `mysp.Close();` into a `finally` block after the exception.

Answer (score 0):

You could let the user configure what port to use, that is how it is usually done.

Or open all available ports, wait for your connection and then close the unused ones.